# Solr DIH regextransformer - processes only one CSV line

Tags: regex, csv, solr, dataimporthandler, dih

Hi I have the following CSV file

```
132 1536130302256087040
133 1536130302256087041
134 1536130302256087042
```

the fields are seperated by a tab. 
Now I have the Dataimporthandler (DIH) for the solr, and I try to import the CSV into solr, but I only get the first line into solr. Thats the result, but the other lines from the CSV are missing:

```
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 1,
    "docs": [ {
        "string": "1536130302256087040",
        "id": "132",
        "_version_": 1536202153221161000
      } ] }
```

Here is my data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" name="fds"/>
    <document>

     <entity name="f" 
     processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
     fileName="myfile.csv" 
     baseDir="/var/www/solr-5.4.0/server/csv/files" 
     recursive="false" 
     rootEntity="true" 
     dataSource="null" >

     <entity 
     onError="continue" 
     name="jc"   
     processor="LineEntityProcessor" 
     url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" 
     dataSource="fds"  
     rootEntity="true" 
     header="false"
     separator="\t"
     transformer="RegexTransformer" >

     <field column="id" name="id" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="^(.*)\t"/>
     <field column="string" name="string" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="\t(.*)$"/>

             </entity>            
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Here is my schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="string" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have **rootEntity=true** for both levels of entities. So, you will only get one document for the outer entity. Try setting the outer level rootEntity to false.

Also, you can just send tab-separated files to the Solr with [CSV processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-IndexingTab-Delimitedfiles), no DIH required.