# Solr Regex - parse tab seperated CSV

Tags: csv, solr, dataimporthandler, dih

Hello I have a CSV which is seperated by tabs for each field:

```
id  name    subject description comments
c4e 10181   Hello1  d1  1
741 10181   Hello2  d2  2
b62 10181   Hello3  d3  3
fd4 10181   Hello4  d4  4
2fb 10181   Hello5  d5  5
```

I wanted to regex it with the solr Regextransformer, to import it via Dataimporthandler (DIH) but eventually the regex isn't working:

```
 <field column="id" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="^(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)\t"/>
 <field column="name" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="\t(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)$"/>
 <field column="subject" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="\t(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)$"/>
 <field column="description" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="\t(.*)\t(.*)$"/>
 <field column="comments" sourceColName="rawLine" regex="\t(.*)$"/>
```

Subject, decription and comments are wrong, they take additionally the previous fields, what is wrong with the regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr DIH regextransformer - processes only one CSV line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629261/solr-dih-regextransformer-processes-only-one-csv-line)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I’d say it’s a problem of greediness. Does it help to replace every occurrence of `.*` in the last 3 lines to `.*?`